# In Blade Runner, what was the Geisha advertising?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner

There is an omnipresent blimp drifting lazily above the city...an advertisement with a Geisha plays over and over.

What is the advertisement? She appears to be popping a pill at one point.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

According to David Dryer (the film's Effects Supervisor), the pill she is swallowing is in fact a **birth control pill**:

> Scott's intentions with this imagery, as related by special effects
>   supervisor, David Dryer, are revealing; *"What happened... was that
>   Ridley and I had a meeting where he told me,'I want a bunch of phony
>   oriental commercials where geisha girls are doing unhealthy things.
>   Smoking, taking drugs or whatever. To kind of continue with the
>   oppressive feeling throughout the landscape"*. **Dryer
>   also reveals the idea he had for the type of pills the geisha is seen
>   to be swallowing, namely, birth control pills: *"This was strictly my
>   idea - it seemed to make sense that birth control would be heavily
>   advertised in such an overpopulated future".*** <sub><sup>[Berliner Chic](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-X6Y4W62sF0C&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=%22David%20Dryer%22%20and%20%22birth%20control%22%20and%20geisha&source=bl&ots=qDJWK3Kypd&sig=DSXOfzMsIHAR18FRQ-7XIGEdFDk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9NG_VJHSHMnuUr2mhJAL&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22David%20Dryer%22%20and%20%22birth%20control%22%20and%20geisha&f=false)</sup></sub>

[IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083658/trivia?item=tr0753873) also identifies the line that is playing:

> In the strange Japanese advertisement shown on the side of a blimp, in
>   which a Geisha-like woman is swallowing a pill, the loud speakers play
>   a line from a Japanese Noh play, saying "*Iri Hi Katamuku*," literally
>   "*the setting sun sinks down*."

For completeness, I'd like to mention that the advert itself is considered to be a parody of an existing Japanese product; [Strong Wakamoto](https://www.wakamoto-pharm.co.jp/english/product/index.html). A yeast-based pill that supposedly keeps you (ahem) regular.

Comment: Bonus: the text down the right-hand side *actually says* 強力わかもと, "Strong Wakamoto". 
(Can a parody of Coca Cola be called as such if it literally has "Coca Cola" in the image?)

Comment: Interesting: Book seems to indicate underpopulated future, due to radiation. Movie does not seem to show over population either -- for example, Sebastian lives alone in a big building. Even the existence of replicants could imply lack of human labor.

Comment: There were plenty of people enough to send them to new worlds. The androids were used in very hazardous jobs, say, mining in Mars